# ¿Cómo puedo saltarme la primera fila al recorrer un archivo csv con un for en php?

Tags: php, csv, fopen

Tengo el siguiente código, que extrae información de un archivo csv:

```
 if (($file = fopen($file_dir, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($recordset = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $columns = count($recordset);
                for ($i = 7; $i < $columns; $i++) {
                    ?>
                    <ul class="list-group" id="myList">
                        <li class="list-group-item" style="padding:.5rem 1.25rem">
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" id="<?php echo $recordset[5] ?>" name="e_cod" value="<?php echo $recordset[4]; ?>" required>
                                <label id="<?php echo $recordset[5] ?>"><?php echo $recordset[5] . "</a><br>"; ?></label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
        <?php
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }
        ?>
```

El resultado es el siguiente:
[image: Resultado]

¿Como puedo hacer para que no me aparezca la primera fila que en este caso es "e_nombre?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algo más o menos como te dice [@erika_chan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/144052/erika-chan), podría ser de la siguiente forma:

```
$conteo = 0;
if (($file = fopen($file_dir, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($recordset = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                $columns = count($recordset);
                for ($i = 7; $i < $columns; $i++) {
                   if($conteo != 0){
                    ?>
                    <ul class="list-group" id="myList">
                        <li class="list-group-item" style="padding:.5rem 1.25rem">
                            <div>
                                <input type="radio" id="<?php echo $recordset[5] ?>" name="e_cod" value="<?php echo $recordset[4]; ?>" required>
                                <label id="<?php echo $recordset[5] ?>"><?php echo $recordset[5] . "</a><br>"; ?></label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
        <?php
                }else{ $conteo++; }
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }
        ?>
```

Según lo que visualicé en la respuesta que te dio [@erika_chan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/144052/erika-chan) me di cuenta que se saltaba el `for`, lo evitaba por completo, entonces, tomando en cuenta eso que cómo era ahí donde insertaba el `html`, pues ahí era dónde se debía hacer el salto.
Revisalo y me dices, ojalá te sirva.

Comment: Este si me funcionó :D
Te lo agradezco, y a @erika_chan también!

Comment: bueno, si ya esta resuelto elimino mi respuesta, te paso un voto por que te salio bien

Comment: Hay una solución más simple, basada en lo que decía @erika_chan ([ver esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24858542/5587982)). ¿Por qué no te funcionaba haciéndolo así? En cuanto a esta respuesta, no explicas de qué modo se resuelve el problema.